# How do I create a shortcode using HTML with an HTML value as shortcode attribute?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to create a shortcode for a **click-to-copy coupon button**. I am using HTML.

How do I use HTML dynamically so that it takes input in the form of shortcode attribute?

This is the HTML code I want to shortcode:

```
<span class="copy-button click-to-copy" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copy-target">
  <span id="copy-target" class="target">Click Here</span>
  <span class="hidden copy">Copy</span>
  <span class="hidden copied">Copied</span>
</span>
```

The part `Click Here` has to be dynamic. It should be replaced by the shortcode attribute.

Suppose the shortcode is `[coupon]` then `Click Here` should have the value that I put inside `[coupon value=" "]` or any other attribute.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/ and https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API have sufficient information on this matter.

Comment: What have you tried and what were your results? Please read about asking questions in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I checked the WordPress documentation as suggested by [Scuzzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61795/scuzzy) and got it working.

I created a separate PHP file and included it in WordPress functions.php

Then I used the following code:

```
<?php
function coupon_function( $atts = array() ) {

    // set up default parameters
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
     'code' => 'Coupon Code Here'
    ), $atts));

    return '<span class="copy-button click-to-copy" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copy-target"><span id="copy-target" class="target">' . $code . '</span><span class="hidden copy">Copy</span><span class="hidden copied">Copied</span></span>';
}
add_shortcode('coupon', 'coupon_function');
?>
```

Then I tried this shortcode `[coupon code="test"]` and it worked perfectly.

Thanks